# download contents from third party S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I am new to S3. A researcher shared his data with us through a public S3 bucket (s3://bucketname). I have created an AWS account with a free trial and am trying to download the data from the shared bucket but cannot seem to find it. I have already tried from the console. I also tried the bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com but I only get the document tree. In the document tree I can see the names of the files that I need to download however I have no way of downloading them. Any tips on how to download the data?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/path/file .
```

Answer (score 0):

> In the document tree I can see the names of the files that I need to download however I have no way of downloading them.

Start with the bucket URL and add the object key on the end.

In the bucket listing you will see, e.g. `<Key>photos/funny/cat.png</Key>`.  That is the object key -- the path and name of the file.

For `example-bucket`, take the bucket URL `https://example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com` + `/` + `photos/funny/cat.png` and there you have the URL to the object, accessible from any browser or other HTTP client.

Answer (score 0):

Your researcher might have given you only the list object permission,

> "s3:ListBucket"

You need

GetObject permissions to those buckets.

Please verify the permissions with your researcher to enable GetObject policy.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install S3 Browser from http://s3browser.com/
2. Go to Accounts -> Add New Account
3. Enter the access ID and secret Key. Third party S3 bucket owner should have provided this to you.
4. Click Add New Account
5. It will prompt you to add Any external S3 bucket. Say yes and Enter the bucket name that u r trying to access. The name has to be exact.

Now you should be able to see the bucket and contents.